# Apache .hatccess rewrites not working for legacy URLS

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla, expressionengine

I'm trying to rewrite some legacy Joomla URLs on a site that's now using ExpressionEngine as its CMS but they're not working.

The ExpressionEngine URL rewrites, i.e. removing index.php from the URL work fine though.

This is what I've got:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on

# This is the one that's not working
  RewriteRule /index.php?option=com_chronocontact&Itemid=54 /contact/  [R=301,L]

# Force www
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
# Redirect index.php Requests
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[^/]*/index\.php [NC]
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET
  RewriteRule ^index\.php(.+) $1 [R=301,L]
# Standard ExpressionEngine Rewrite
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(gclid=.*)
  RewriteRule ^(.+) /index.php?/ [L,PT]
  RewriteCond $1 !\.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png) [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond  $1 !^(assets|css|images|tinymce|js|min|cms|themes|index\.php|admin\.php|favicon\.ico|index\.php|path\.php|php\.ini) [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.+) /index.php?/ [L]

</IfModule>
```

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing is the stray `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on` that you have at the top. It looks like it belongs to the rule under it, as in:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

As far as the rule that you have commented that doesn't work, the `?` is a reserved character for regular expressions, and your pattern actually says that the second `p` in `/index.php` is "optional". Additionally, you can't match against the query string in a rewrite rule, you need to use a rewrite condition and match against the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_chronocontact&Itemid=54$
RewriteRule ^(index.php)?$ /contact/? [R=301,L]
```

is probably more along the lines of what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, that's very close to what I want except that the page redirects to /contact/?option=com_chronocontact&Itemid=54 Any way to remove the querystring too?